# How do large companies deal with Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

I am investigating how to migrate our source control from SVN to Mercurial. One thing I am not sure how to deal with is usernames in commits. From what I've seen, there is no way to force an HG user to use a specific username, even if specified in Mercurial.ini, the user can override it in commits with the **-u** flag in **hg commit**.

How do companies deal with this? there is nothing to prevent developer A to commit something in his repository as developer B, and then pushing it to someone else.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't say our company is large (4 developers), but it's never been an issue for us so far.  I haven't seen any way to prevent that behavior either in my searching.  I guess it comes down to an issue of trust amongst your developers.

Unrelated, we did successfully migrate from SVN to Mercurial about two years ago so I may be able to answer other questions you have.

---

EDIT: An idea:

I'm not sure how you were planning on setting up your topology, but we have a server that functions as the central repository for all our repos.  It is possible to push changes between developers (bypassing the central server), but we never do that.  We always commit locally and then push/pull from/to the central server.  Additionally, we use https and windows authentication to authenticate with this central server.

If you're planning on having something like this, you could create a hook on the server (see [repository events](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html)) (maybe the `precommit` event) that would verify that the user name in each commit being pushed is the same as the authenticated user from the web server.

Not sure if this would work, but it sounds plausable.

Comment: Agreed, trust is key (I'd say always), but in a large company you cannot rely on trust completely, that's why security policies exist.

Comment: @SoManyGoblins I'm not sure if you're notified with edits, but I edited my answer to add an idea.

Comment: I've thought of that, yes, it's a good idea, but I was wondering if that is how large companies deal with it, maybe there was a more generally accepted way of doing this. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I think the event I need to handle is the pretxnchangegroup event.

Answer (score 0):

## Another attempt(s)

### Path-based ACLs in pseudo-CVCS workflow

If you'll use "controlled anarchy" workflow (p2p communications aren't controlled, resticted AND trusted and single authoritative source is common push-target), you can use "Branch Per Developer" paradigm. I.e - with [ACL extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/AclExtension) on central repo the following restrictions apply:

- Nobody can push to default branch
- Each developer can push **only in his personal branch** (under any name, name means nothing, auth-data for tracking is branch-name)
- Only trusted mergers can work with repo-Central (merge dev-branches to default, NO rebase|NO history rewrite in dev-branches)
- Each mergeset in default branch contain authentication piece - source branch

### Signing branches

If you can't trust (and you **must not trust**) username in commits, you can trust strong crypto. Mercurial have at least two extensions, which allow digitally sign commits, thus providing accurate (so-so, see notes below) information about the authorship with own advantages and disadvantages in both cases

- [Commitsigs Extension Wiki](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommitsigsExtension) and [Signing Mercurial Changesets on Windows](http://dhickey.ie/post/2011/05/02/Siging-Mercurial-Changesets-on-Windows.aspx) mini-HowTo are complete enough to understand and demonstrate all aspects of the start. Pro: no additional commits for signing, you can't (by design) sign old historic commits. Contra: not-so-nice output of needed commands (see screenshots in Damian's post for log and verifysigs), because it's GnuPG (no PKI), theoretically it's possible to create and use key-pair for any name-email and only "extra" comparison will show two different keys for one user
- [GPG extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/GpgExtension) and [Approval Reports](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Workflows#Approval_Reports) from wiki as quick-start. Pro: <strike>can use pgp-keys or openssl-certs (TBT!!!) (where openssl means one corporate source of issued certs)</strike>, more readable and informative output of sigcheck command. Contra:

> commiting changes to a .hgsigs file in the root of the working copy
>   and so it requires extra changesets to be made. This makes it
>   infeasible to sign all changesets. The .hgsigs file must also be
>   merged like any other file when branches are merged.

and at last file can be modified by hand by malicious user as any other file in WC

**Edit and bugfixing**
Openssl can be used in Commitsigs, not GPG extension